# [HELP]Ubuntu Installation process?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 15.10

I wanted to install Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit.
I have windows 32 bit installed and i want to install Ubuntu alongside windows(I don't want my data to be deleted).
I have 4 drives C: , D: , E: , :F and i want to install on e drive only. I have 250 GB space in E drive of which i want only 100 GB .
Can anyone give me detailed steps according to my criteria?
Regards!

Comment: check this [post](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) . This may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot into your live CD , select "Try Ubuntu". Search **GParted Partition Editor** in dash board, And free 100GB of space from your E drive. Then apply the changes.

Now click on install Ubuntu (which should be on your Desktop) and follow the Instructions given in the following link.

[**How to use manual partitioning during installation?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

I think there is complete details in the given link for you to install Ubuntu alongside windows.

Happy Installing.

Comment: Here is a link to learn how to use GParted Partition Editor:  http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual

Comment: Refer MicrosoftLinux's comment to know how to make a live CD

Comment: Is it okay if i dont make swap partition?

Comment: I have 100gb of space.So please tell me what partitions i have to create according to this!

Comment: Its is kinda not OK :P. Swap area is necessary for doing hibernation in Ubuntu. The splitting of 100GB is left to you. But as suggested Provide swap area grater than or equal to your RAM size. and give '/' some 60Gb.. and remaining to home. Once again It is your choice to give any amount of space.